# Binding doesn't update the property

Tags: silverlight, data-binding

I have DataDependentControl with dependency properties defined:
**TextVisibility, CalendarVisibility, ComboControlVisibility**.
When I select some values in outside combobox with enumerated datatypes, the properties mentioned above are updated to ***Visibility*** enumeration value, but binding doesn't update Visibility property on inside controls:

```
        <Views:DataDependentControl x:Name="typeValue">
            <StackPanel x:Name="container">
                <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxControl" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=typeValue, Path=TextVisibility, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <Controls:Calendar x:Name="CalendarControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=typeValue, Path=CalendarVisibility}"/>
                <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxControl" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=typeValue, Path=ComboControlVisibility}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Views:DataDependentControl>
```

DataDependentControl has **DataType** property.
According to DataType I hide or collapse child controls via following properties:
ComboControlVisibility, CalendarVisibility or TextVisibility

**DataType** property within DataDependentControl is defined as follows:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DataTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            DataTypePropertyName,
            typeof (DataTypeEnum),
            typeof (DataDependentControl),
            new PropertyMetadata(ValueChangedCallback));
```

**ValueChangedCallback** function is defined as follows:

```
private static void ValueChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var thisObject = (DataDependentControl)d;
            var newValue = (DataTypeEnum) e.NewValue;

            switch (newValue)
            {
                case DataTypeEnum.Bool:
                    thisObject.ComboControlVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    thisObject.CalendarVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    thisObject.TextVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

....

**Example** of TextVisibility, CalendarVisibility or ComboControlVisibility is here:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextVisibilityProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            TextVisibilityPropertyName,
            typeof (Visibility),
            typeof (DataDependentControl),
            null);
```

All in all:

Inside the `<StackPanel/>`:

If selected datatype is "string" there should be visible

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBoxControl"/>
```

If selected datatype is "DateTime" there should be visible

```
<Controls:Calendar/>
```

If selected datatype is "Boolean" there should be visible

```
<ComboBox/>
```

DataDependentControl has "DataType" property which is defined in combobox. "DataType" is databound:

```
<Views:DataDependentControl x:Name="typeValue"
                                        DataType="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=DataTypes, Converter={StaticResource DataTypeReverseConverter}}"
```

Comment: Can you please provide your code-behind (with the Dependency properties) as well? Thanks.

Comment: I have updated info. Thank you.

Comment: There was an error in description: "typeValue" is not a combobox, but common user control which defines DataType property and child controls Visibility are updated according to DataType

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you're trying to your dependency properties on a `ComboBox`, even though they're defined by your `DataDependentControl`. If the visibility of the child controls is tied to the visibility of the `ComboBox`, why not just do this?

```
<Views:DataDependentControl x:Name="typeValue">
    <StackPanel x:Name="container">
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxControl" Visibility="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=typeValue}"/>
        <Controls:Calendar x:Name="CalendarControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Visibility="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=typeValue}"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxControl"  Visibility="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=typeValue}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Views:DataDependentControl>
```

Or, even better:

```
<Views:DataDependentControl x:Name="typeValue">
    <StackPanel x:Name="container" Visibility="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=typeValue}">
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxControl"/>
        <Controls:Calendar x:Name="CalendarControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxControl"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Views:DataDependentControl>
```

Comment: I have added information after words "All in all"
The visibility is selective. Not all controls should visible or collapsed

Comment: BTW, your way would be good if to develop IValuConvertor for each child control inside DataDependentControl and to databind Visibility to outside combobox value.

Comment: There was an error in description: "typeValue" is not a combobox, but common user control which defines DataType property and child controls Visibility property is updated according to DataType